# jQuery errors - Uncaught TypeError: q.indexOf is not a function

Tags: jquery, debugging

Im getting the following error which is used to remove hashes that append to the browser URL. Im using a live view via Visual Code Studio. These errors appear in the console debugger

```
Uncaught TypeError: q.indexOf is not a function
    jQuery 5
        trigger
        trigger
        each
        each
        trigger
    <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:5500/assets/js/hash.js:5
    jQuery 8
        j
        fireWith
        ready
        I
        promise
        <anonymous>
        <anonymous>
        <anonymous>
jquery-2.1.0.min.js:3:4436
    jQuery 5
        trigger
        trigger
        each
        each
        trigger
    <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:5500/assets/js/hash.js:5
    jQuery 8
        j
        fireWith
        ready
        I
        (Async: EventListener.handleEvent)
    promise
        <anonymous>
        <anonymous>
        <anonymous>
```

and the actual JS for hash.js

```
jQuery(function () {
  // get the anchor link buttons
  const menuBtn = $(".scroll-to");
  // when each button is clicked
  menuBtn.trigger(() => {
    // set a short timeout before taking action
    // so as to allow hash to be set
    setTimeout(() => {
      // call removeHash function after set timeout
      removeHash();
    }, 5); // 5 millisecond timeout in this case
  });

  // removeHash function
  // uses HTML5 history API to manipulate the location bar
  function removeHash() {
    history.replaceState(
      "",
      document.title,
      window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + window.location.search
    );
  }
});
```

Im not actually sure how to approach the error. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you should make sure the code in hash.js run **after html is mouted** (document is ready).
Second, You should **log** these value (window.location.origin, window.location.pathname, window.location.search) to know **what type they are**, and **make sure their type is string**.
Finally, You can **post your code** to [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/), everyone can get to know better about them, and feel easier to support.